# Drawing an indifference curve that tangents a line in JSXGraph

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

I've started to use JSXGraph to draw a function. It should be a simple straight line (budget curve) that has a half-circle as his tangent (an indifference curve).
Furthermore the tangent should move with the line, if the line is moved.

Is this possible in JSXGraph?

Edit: The Curve and the function should look similar to this graph:
https://www.economicsonline.co.uk/Pictures2017/Grid-indifference-Basic-Equilibrium-new.png

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with JSXGraph. One approach is to start with a point *A* and fix the slope *s* of the budget curve through *A* as well as the radius *r* of the circle line.
Doing the relatively straightforward math gives as coordinates of the center *M* of the circle:

```
M = A + r / sqrt(r*r + 1) * [-s, 1]
```

The equation of the circle line is

```
(y - M_y)^2 + (x - M_x)^2 = r^2
```

It follows that the indifference curve is

```
y = -sqrt(r^2 - (x - M_x)^2) + M_y
```

We take the negative square root, since we want to take the lower semicircle as indifference curve. A working example is at http://jsfiddle.net/4sg1dpq8/